# Wolfram Cloud's Sum give wrong position

Tags: formatting, wolfram-cloud

Run this code in wolfram cloud.

```
Sum[((-1)^(i + 1)*Binomial[n, i]*(n - i)!)/n!, {i, 1, n}]
```

[image]

Click Output to get the code.

[image]

Gives

```
UnderoverscriptBox["\:2211", "n", RowBox[{"i", "=", "1"}]]FractionBox[RowBox[{SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"-", "1"}], ")"}], RowBox[{"1", "+", "i"}]], " ", RowBox[{"Binomial", "[", RowBox[{"n", ",", "i"}], "]"}], " ", RowBox[{RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{RowBox[{"-", "i"}], "+", "n"}], ")"}], "!"}]}], RowBox[{"n", "!"}]]
```

Then paste it into wolfram cloud notebook.

[image]

the limit of Sum is reversed. So is this a bug?

The notebook is here

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/e8f52da4-1dd5-4bf3-b931-79d8406f3043

Comment: What is your question exactly? Please provide as much information as possible.